# Symfony2.0 validation with Regex

Tags: regex, symfony, annotations, validation

I'm working on a **Symfony2.0** form with a text field. I use **Annotation** to validate the field. The field has the following validation:

```
 * @Assert\MinLength(limit=2, message="At least two characters")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *           pattern= "/\d/",
 *           match=   false,
 *           message= "This text cannot contain numbers" 
 * )
```

Notice that the *Regex* assertion comes from [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html#basic-usage).

So, I expect that all the characters except the numbers can be used! However, When I put some special chars like "**ò**", the form is not validated and the error message "*This text cannot contain numbers*" is returned.

I checked the Regex string at http://www.regextester.com/ and seems to work right!

Any idea why that validation in Symfony2.0 works bad?
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the *Regex* proposed on the **Symfony2.0** official doc as follows:

```
 @Assert\Regex(pattern= "/[0-9]/")
```

and now the form works well.

A final thought! I really don't understand why such characters are meant to be digits by using the Regex **\d**. Many non-English words use that characters.

Comment: You should use the Type constraint : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html